# is restarting apache service needed with any changes to rewritemap file?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

I am using a perl script file as a map file in RewriteMap directive.
As i read the apache load the script once at the beginning, So is it needed to reload or restart apache after any changes to this script file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [rewrite maps](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) are only registered when Apache is starting. And when using external programs as rewrite maps (i.e. map type `pgr`) the program files need to be locked with [`RewriteLock`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelock):

> This directive sets the filename for a synchronization lockfile which mod_rewrite needs to communicate with `RewriteMap` *programs*. Set this lockfile to a local path (not on a NFS-mounted device) when you want to use a rewriting map-program. It is not required for other types of rewriting maps.

But the other map types can be changed afterwards:

> For plain text and DBM format files the looked-up keys are cached in-core until the *mtime* of the mapfile changes or the server does a restart. This way you can have map-functions in rules which are used for **every** request. This is no problem, because the external lookup only happens once!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the response above is correct, reload seems to be fine.

You can do "ps aux | grep YOUR_REWRITE_PROGRAM" to check the PID/start time of your rewrite map program.

Apache reload seems to set a new PID/start time for these processes, so I would assume new processes have started, a reload may be fine.